# How to test this specific selector?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I'm testing my NgRx code, on my selectors I have two selectors:

```
export const selectSlice = (state: AppState) => state.slice;

export const selectErrors = createSelector(
  selectSlice,
  state => state.errors
);
```

I can test selectErrors pretty easily with projector but I can't test the first one, it always stays as "function uncovered" on Instanbul. I tried the following:

```
it('should return call to selectSlice', () => {
    const selector = selectors.selectSlice;
    store.select(selector);

    expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith(selector);
});
```

How am I supposed to test it?

Edit: This is my test for the errors selector:

```
it('should return call to selectErrors', () => {
    const selector = selectors.selectErrors;
    store.select(selector);

    expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith(selector);
    expect(
      selector.projector({
        errors: [
          {
            message: 'Mock error'
          }
        ]
      }).length
    ).toEqual(1);
  });
```

Comment: How does your selectErrors  test look like?

Comment: I put my other test above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is uncovered because you're using the selector's `projector` function which skips executing the selectors and only runs the projector function.

To get codecoverage for it, you should:

- not use the `projector` function as it's a fairly simple selector
- or write a test for it as follows (because a selector is just a function, you can invoke it and test the output):

```
expect(selectSlice({ slice: 'foo'})).toEqual('foo')
```

Personally, I don't see any added value to writing these tests and these might be time consuming - see my article [How I test my NgRx selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/how-i-test-my-ngrx-selectors) for more info.